# Corrupting compilers

Tags: compiler-construction, coding-style

Is it possible that I might possibly write a code that corrupts the compiler? Means can bad programming practices lead to such a situation where I might end up harming the compiler and I am assuming that the code I have written is not some sort of virus which is specifically designed to do this?

Comment: Corrupt the compiler?  Does your code lead it down the path to too much alcohol, narcotics and loose women?  My JVM has been corrupted for a long time, and I consider my code to be better off for it.

Comment: That was a bit snarky.  Not at all in line with the "Summer of Love" http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/  But this id not a constructive question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking the compiler consists of static code. Static code will be rerun from scratch each time you run the program. So as long you don't have access to it, you cannot corrupt the compiler.

There are programming languages that let you extend using the compiler. But even if you can extend the language, it is likely that the compiler will start afresh each run. Furthermore, it is unlikely that you can trigger anything harmful this way.

There are compiler bugs and they may be triggered. But normally that will just result in a failed build.

Now if you have a `Makefile` you can change anything the user has access to. So building an application could trigger unwanted side effects. Install scripts are the most likely to influence a system of course, as they normally run with elevated priviledges.

Answer (score 1):

No. At least not by accident (which is what I assume you are talking about when you mention "bad programming practices")

Usually, whatever you do has no effect on the compiler binary, so even if you manage to corrupt the memory, when the compiler is restarted it's completely "repaired".

A major exception to this rule is if you actually change the compiler binary (e.g. using a File I/O API to rewrite the executable), but this is notoriously hard to do by accident.

Corrupting the compiler is not that easy. You'd probably have to find a security vulnerability in the compiler and then exploit it to change the result. Hard to do by accident, even harder to get a working executable as the result.

If a person wanted to force the compiler to generate a virus, there are far easier ways to do this:

- Actually write the code for a virus and normally compile it. In this case, the compiler is working exactly as it should as the virus source code is correctly converted into a virus binary.
- Intentionally and directly change the compiler binary.

If you are concerned that downloading code from the Internet and compiling it might result in a virus, then that concern might be justified. However, as I mentioned before, it's ridiculously hard to properly exploit the compiler compared to the alternative ways to produce/spread viruses.
Either way, inspecting the source code should be enough to dismiss such concerns for practical purposes.

Comment: Barring a bug in the compiler, how would you be able to corrupt it, even intentionally, just by compiling the code? Even if the code did access the compiler binary, that wouldn't happen until the code is actually executed, no?

Comment: @sepp2k For most programming languages, a bug would indeed be necessary. (unless the language had some sort of preprocessor that allowed File I/O, but even then it could be argued that the code for the preprocessor had been interpreted)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible except if there's a very strange and unlikely bug in the compiler that would be triggered by such code.

Comment: are you sure means I am not saying that you are wrong but is the compiler safe from our programs?